# Unique array with member names

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

i have an array with group members (last_name, first_name), but in the group "Testgroup" is another group "Testgroup2". The bad thing is that i dont get unique values from both groups.

Can anyone help ? It´s Javascript

```
var manager_list = new Array;
var manager_list = new Array;
var srvData = new spl_srv();


    <LIST PREFIX=list WHERE="group.last_name = 'Testgroup'">
        var wc = "group = U'$list.member'";
        var data = srvData.read("grpmem", wc, "member.last_name|member.first_name|member");
        var anz  = srvData.getcount();
        if(anz > 0) {
            for (i=0; i<anz; i++){
                var UU_ID = srvData.getdata(i,2);
                UU_ID = UU_ID.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"");
                manager_list.push(srvData.getdata(i,0)+', '+srvData.getdata(i,1)+'@,@'+UU_ID);
            }
        } 
        else {

        manager_list.push("$list.member.last_name, $list.member.first_name@,@$list.member");
        }
```

Comment: What is this? `<LIST PREFIX=list WHERE="group.last_name = 'Testgroup'">`

Comment: It´s a special programming language for our ticket tool and give me the members of the groups...

Comment: Please show the data of your array.

Comment: Last_name_person1, First_name_person1@,@10D638FD34E3774C8ED11675B396235A,Last_name_person2, First_name_person2@,@30D1E53196333B4480F2292AD3B80DE9,Last_name_person3, First_name_person3@,@69E8AE5DD8A6754C95777884A981E0A8,Last_name_person4, First_name_person4@,@80A77E7D216DB64FB813274E0A827850,Last_name_person5, First_name_person5@,@1EF167033F3D014AA72B9885A647897C,Last_name_person6, First_name_person6@,@AAD37DD5FD11FC4AAE1E435766B97F6F,Last_name_person7, First_name_person7@,@AF49F3A79C4B9B44A9E768F52C98DBF6,Last_name_person1, First_name_person1@,@10D638FD34E3774C8ED11675B396235A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get Unique values from array(Removing duplicates)

1. `var uniqueManagers = [];
       $.each(manager_list, function(i, el){
           if($.inArray(el, uniqueManagers) === -1) uniqueManagers.push(el);
       });`
2. `let uniqueManagers = Array.from(new Set(manager_list))`

Your code should be something like below

```
var manager_list = new Array;
var manager_list = new Array;
var srvData = new spl_srv();
       <LIST PREFIX=list WHERE="group.last_name = 'Testgroup'">
        var wc = "group = U'$list.member'";
        var data = srvData.read("grpmem", wc, "member.last_name|member.first_name|member");
        var anz  = srvData.getcount();
        if(anz > 0) {
            for (i=0; i<anz; i++){
                var UU_ID = srvData.getdata(i,2);
                UU_ID = UU_ID.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"");
                manager_list.push(srvData.getdata(i,0)+', '+srvData.getdata(i,1)+'@,@'+UU_ID);
            }
        } 
        else {

        manager_list.push("$list.member.last_name, $list.member.first_name@,@$list.member");
        }
  manager_list = Array.from(new Set(manager_list))
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am a beginner. Can you copy my code and insert your code to the right place? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should flatten your array then filter:

```js
const data = yourArray.reduce(
  (acc, current) => acc.concat(current), 
[]);
  
const uniqueItems = [...new Set(data)];
```

Comment: Can you copy my code and insert your code to the right place? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner simple and functional solution and it uses a `standard` and `built-in` function rather than a home-rolled solution.

```
var manager_list = ['smith', 'john', 'phil', 'john'];
var unique = manager_list.filter(function(item, i, arr){ return arr.indexOf(item) === i; });

// result = ['smith', 'john', 'phil'];
```